て verb grammar + が？

待て！
待てができるほど俺はいい子じゃないよ？

The character is flirting with his girlfriend and she tells him "wait" when he goes for a kiss. Then he replies this to her. Why is 待て here used? It should be noted the character is American and is sometimes noted to have poor Japanese.

Do people in your country/culture use "Stay"(待て) "Sit"(お座り) commands when training their dogs?

This is the 命令形; 待つ with て is 待って

It's because 待て is treated as a lexicalized noun here. See: Basic Commands to train dogs in Japanese!
Whether the woman is treating the man like a dog depends on the context, but the man clearly has in mind "Wait" as a command for dogs.
